# How should I be using filters and is_single together?

Tags: filters, conditional-tags

I have a plugin that uses this filter to add some content to a Custom Post Type.

```
// From plugin:
add_filter( 'the_content', 'sixtenpresssermons_get_meta', 15 );
```

I'd like to remove that filter on certain views (singles).

I'd like to do so using code in my theme files - without editing the plugin.

I tried with the code below in functions.php, but obviously it's not working.

```
// Not working, in functions.php
if ( is_single('sermon') ) {
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'sixtenpresssermons_get_meta', 15 )
}
```

Can I use conditionals with a filter like this, or how can I remove the filter on singles only?

Comment: It's too early to do it that way, WP doesn't know if `is_single` is true or false yet in `functions.php`. Depending on how the plugin is built it might not have had a chance to even add the filter yet for you to remove it

Comment: Ok. That makes sense (I think.) Thanks for explaining it in plain english to me. I guess that is why most other code I see wrap the condition in a function?

Comment: If I were to try and wrap it in a function, is there a particulary good action (is that the correct term?) to try and use, so it's executed at the right time?

Comment: It's generally not a great idea to make function calls in `functions.php` or a plugin at the top level, it avoids the problem of _ordering_. I was going to suggest adding `if ( is_singular() ) { return; }` to the hook as an answer but I see you can't change the original, I'm not sure what the appropriate action to hook into for this would be right now to write an answer though

Comment: Ok, no worries. For what it's worth, the simple `remove_filter` statement in `functions.php` (without the conditional) works. But removes it from all instances, and not just singular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in `functions.php`, but you have to make sure the function is hooked into `wp`. Any earlier than that and `is_single` is undefined.

Try adding this to `functions.php`:

```
/**
 * Unhooks sixtenpresssermons_get_meta from the_content if currently on single post.
 */
function sx_unhook_sixtenpresssermons_get_meta() {
    // Do nothing if this isn't single post
    if ( ! is_single() ) {
        return;
    }

    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'sixtenpresssermons_get_meta', 15 );
}
add_action( 'wp', 'sx_unhook_sixtenpresssermons_get_meta' );
```

Comment: Thank you - I just discovered the WP hook (?) myself. But your code is much neater then  my attempts. Thanks!